# "No data to display" while populating JSON data into YUI DataTable

Tags: javascript, json, yui

I am newbie in YUI, can't find how to fix this issue. I am using code from YUI examples and trying to make it work for my json url..

```
<div id="pizza" class="yui3-skin-sam dt-example"></div>
<script>
YUI().use("datasource-get", "datasource-jsonschema", "datatable-base-deprecated", "datatable-datasource-deprecated", function (Y) {

var url = "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo",
dataSource,
table;

dataSource = new Y.DataSource.Get({ source: url });

dataSource.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, {
schema: {
    resultListLocator: "geonames",
    resultFields: ["fcodeName", "toponymName", "countrycode", "fcl", "fclName", "name", "wikipedia", "lng", "fcode", "geonameId", "lat", "population"]
}
});

table = new Y.DataTable.Base({
columnset: ["fcodeName", "toponymName", "countrycode", "fcl", "fclName", "name", "wikipedia", "lng", "fcode", "geonameId", "lat", "population"]    });

table.plug(Y.Plugin.DataTableDataSource, { datasource: dataSource });

table.render("#pizza");

table.datasource.load({ request: url });
});
</script>
```

and my json response is

```
{"geonames":[{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Mexico City","countrycode":"MX","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Mexiko-Stadt","wikipedia":"","lng":-99.12766456604,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":3530597,"lat":19.428472427036,"population":12294193}, same pattern....]}
```

I think I am missing some basic concepts. I apologies if this question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Javascript code you need. You can test it using this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/pfHAm/

```
YUI().use("datasource-get", "datasource-jsonschema", "datatable-base-deprecated", "datatable-datasource-deprecated", function (Y) {

var url = "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?",
    query = "north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=test1",
    dataSource,
    table;

dataSource = new Y.DataSource.Get({ source: url });

dataSource.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, {
    schema: {
        resultListLocator: "geonames",
        resultFields: ["fcodeName", "toponymName", "countrycode", "fcl", "fclName", "name", "wikipedia", "lng", "fcode", "geonameId", "lat", "population"]
    }
});

table = new Y.DataTable.Base({
    columnset: ["fcodeName", "toponymName", "countrycode", "fcl", "fclName", "name", "wikipedia", "lng", "fcode", "geonameId", "lat", "population"]    
});

table.plug(Y.Plugin.DataTableDataSource, { datasource: dataSource });

table.render("#pizza");

table.datasource.load({ request: query });
});​
```

Comment: Hi thanx for the reply, If I am correct you are splitting the url and it is working :(. I have another url(rest: https://somedomain.com/service/lookup/key/value) and it doesn't have list/array name. it looks something like this [{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Mexico City","countrycode":"MX","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Mexiko-Stadt","wikipedia":"","lng":-99.12766456604,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":3530597,"lat":19.428472427036,"population":12294193}, same pattern....]. Now how to deal with resultListLocator, url, query. sry asking this here

Comment: hi, can you please look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TdFqz/ I was trying to do it for my rest url. but I couldn't able to get data. I tried what you have suggested. Is it valid to do for a rest URL? I just simulated my rest call data.

Comment: when the line `table.datasource.load({})` executes, it sends a request to your server and appends an extra parameter to the query string `callback=YUI.Env.DataSource.callbacks.yui_3_6_0_2_1354073659810_155`. The parameter value is random and in order for the json to be populated in the table, you need to wrap it in this function name. You need to modify your myData.json to look read `YUI.Env.DataSource.callbacks.yui_3_6_0_2_1354073659810_155(...you current json output...)`. Because the function name is dynamic, you won't be able to do this with a static file.